# How to add items to Mongo array using Jongo?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, mongodb, jongo

I'm using Jongo to query mongodb. The problem is that when I try to add items to an array field I get the error that says

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: {$addToSet:{bodyParameters:[ {
>   "first" : { "weight" : 1.0 , "height" : 2.0 , "waist" : 3.0 , "biceps"
>   : 4.0 , "chest" : 5.0 , "forearm" : 6.0 , "wrist" : 7.0 , "neck" : 8.0
>   , "hip" : 9.0 , "buttocks" : 10.0 , "shin" : 11.0} , "second" :
>   "20130609"}]} cannot be parsed

My method looks that way

```
public void updateBodyParameters(Profile profile) {
        getCollection().update("{_id:#}", profile.getUsername()).with(
                "{$addToSet:{bodyParameters:#}", profile.getBodyParameters()
        );
    }
```

Body parameters is a class containing this

```
public class Tuple<E, T> implements Serializable {
private E first;
private T second;
```

And it is created as

```
ArrayList<Tuple<BodyParameters, String>>
```

and the BodyParameters class contains fields

```
private double weight;
private double height;
private double waist;
private double biceps;
private double chest;
private double forearm;
private double wrist;
private double neck;
private double hip;
private double buttocks;
private double shin;
```

Tell me please what's the problem with update

Comment: Can you please provide the document structure you're using? I can figure out what you're trying to achieve: is bodyParameters already existing in the document; are you trying to add multiple items to it? Thanks. Maybe trying to achieve this direcly in the mongo shell will help: 'cannot be parsed' means that your query is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing curly brace, it should be:

```
"{$addToSet:{bodyParameters:#}}", profile.getBodyParameters()
```

Note that there should be *two* closing braces after the #.